# Options for web video conferencing?

Tags: video, web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best video conference software](https://superuser.com/questions/56205/best-video-conference-software)

I have web site and i want to video converefence with my customers.. What you will suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

For only two participants, **[Skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/)** will suffice.

If you need more, **[ooVoo](http://www.oovoo.com/)** offers pretty good quality and decent price plans.

[image]

Comment: You fastest gun in the west!